# Can't ping 2 machines through a switch

Tags: networking, ping

2 machines are connected through a switch. I have configured static IPs for both of them.

Machine 1 is 192.168.0.3, whereas machine 2 is 192.168.0.5. Both have 255.255.255.0 for netmask address.

I can't figure out why I can't ping them. I might have misunderstanding something about switch, but it should work directly to my mind, shouldn't it?

`ip a s` gives on

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fd_code1 master br0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:1f:c6:9c:7b:2f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.3/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global eno1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Machine 2

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:d9:fc:7b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.5/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::f994:a8c8:c936:1b60/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: after ping (sucessfull or not), what is the result of ` /sbin/arp -an`  ?

Comment: From 1, it is `? (192.168.0.5) at <incomplete> on eno1`

Comment: Also, arp-scan gives me the mac address of the other machine

Comment: please edit your post with result of ` ip a s` on both host.

Comment: Test to narrow down if it's a problem with the switch, or configuration of the hosts: Connect the two hosts directly with a single ethernet cable, see if they can ping each other.

Comment: Just a wild guess, on host is pluged on "uplink" port ?

Comment: Not sure what you are talking about @Archemar.

Comment: @dirkt: I can't ping them directly, but am I not supposed to use a crossover cable for that? (I don't have one)

Comment: If both NIC's are gigabit, you do not need a crossover cable. The gigabit spec includes autocrossover as a requirement. Many modern 100 mbit chipsets include autocrossover, too. So just give it a try. You won't hurt anything.

Comment: I didn't know thanks! So in the end, it did not work directly through a crossover. But then I deleted my change in machine 1 on netplan (I tried to make a bridge), reboot both computers, and it magically worked! (with and without the switch). So thanks guys!

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure cables, etc are OK? Plugged in right?

Do the "idiot lights" (if available) of the cards show activity? The lights on the switch?

Check the switch configuration, perhaps you plugged the machines into separate VLANs? Or this is a "smart" switch which believes it lives in some different IPv4 network?

Check the local firewall setups, they might be blocking ICMP (ping(1) does an ICMP ECHO-REQUEST).

Check packet counters on the interfaces to check nothing is blocking output.

Comment: Thanks @vonbrand. It appears it was related to a bad configuration on netplan on machine 1.

Comment: @pl-94 please answer your own question to close the matter (and give later readers something to check).

Comment: Alright, I am just waiting to understand [what exactly is wrong in the netplan configuration](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1037810/share-internet-to-ethernet-network-from-wireless-connections-with-netplan)